# Conditions on matrix A for non-zero singular values to be equal?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

Are there any results which discuss when non-zero singular values $\sigma_i$ of a square (complex) matrix $A$ are all the same?

This question could be reframed as when are the non-zero eigenvalues of $AA^{\dagger}$ the same, but I couldn't seem to find much on this either.

An alternative, tangential, question could also be, given that square matrix $B$ has all non-zero singular values equal, what properties does square matrix $C$ have such that the  singular values of $CB$ are still all equal (although as I understand it, this is perhaps a harder problem).

Any avenues of discussion or useful references would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What sort of results are you looking for?  For example, do you consider "$\det{\!(AA^*-\lambda)}$ has a multiple root" to be a snarky non-answer?

Comment: Oh yes that is an important clarification thank you - I'm wondering if there is any structure to the matrix itself? E.g. the columns of a unitary matrix are orthonormal under the standard complex inner product. Should I update my question with this too?